# timeline of product launch based on minimum products sold

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dimension "Products" that has several iphone generations, let's say, iphone4, iphone5, iphone6, iphone7, iphone8. I also have a measure "Number sold" that indicates, the number of phones that are sold. I finally have a "Date" dimension. With this information I am able to see a daily trend of phones sold on a given day based on the generation. Pretty straightforward!

I define the launch date of an iphone as the day where there are at least 50 iphones sold on a given day (let's call this iphone release date). The visualization I'd like to have is to show the exact date on the x-axis and a square, or circle (or any other kind of visualization) labelled with the iphone generation that reached at least 50 units sold on that day.

So to be clear, for instance, 30 iphone4 were sold on 3/3, 52 on 3/4, 63 on 3/5, etc (this would be SUM(Number sold)). I only want to see some kind of mark on the chart on 3/4 indicating "iphone4". This would tell me that 3/4 was the launch date for iphone4, under my assumption that a launch date is when I have at least 50 iphone4 sold that day. Similarly, I would be able to see launch dates for other iphone generations.

How do I do that achieve this in Tableau, and how do I do so in an appealing way?